# Unable to connect to Mongo DB using mongoose with X509 user

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-modules

I am using nodeJS for my project and using mongoose module to connect to mongo db. Connection was working fine with the username/password approach. However when changing to X509 authentication, I am unable to connect to the DB.

Error thrown while connecting to DB - `"err":{"name":"MongoError","message":"auth failed","ok":0,"errmsg":"auth failed","code":18}}`

```
node version - v8.11.3
npm version  - 5.6.0
Mongo Db version - 3.4.14
mongoose version in package json - "^4.8.7"
```

Code snippet below,

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
var connection = null;
var dbString = "mongodb://host1:10901,host2:1902/dbname?replicaSet=replset&readPreference=secondaryPreferred";
var fs = require('fs')

connection = mongoose.createConnection(dbString, {
    user: encodeURIComponent("C=US,ST=California,O=Company Inc.,OU=management:group.123456,CN=dbname-role-user-repl.mydomain.com"),
    auth: { authMechanism: "MONGODB-X509", authSource: '$external' },
    server: {
        ssl: true,
        sslValidate: true,
        sslCA: fs.readFileSync(path to CA file),
        sslCert: fs.readFileSync(path to cert file),
        sslKey: fs.readFileSync(path to kep file),
        sslPass: "password"
    }
});

connection.once("open", function () {
    console.log("App is connected to  DB -- " + dbString);
});
connection.once("close", function () {
    console.log("App disconnected from  DB -- " + dbString);
});
connection.on("error", function (err) {
    console.error("App failed to connect to  DB -- " + dbString, err);
});

module.exports = {
    connection: connection,
    mongoose: mongoose
}
```

Did anyone else face similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

If it will be of any help to others, I found the fix and below is what it is.

Updating the mongoose to version 5.2.5 and removing the encoding(ie encodeURIComponent) on the user string resolved the issue.